# Error while updating/deleting records using Entity Framework DB2 database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, db2

Hello I've a Db2 table called Employee and there is a primary key on All 4 columns

```
| EmployeeID | EmployeeName         |Email                      |     EmpVersion |
| --------   | --------------        | --------                 | -------------- |
|1          |Christoforo Rowcliffe  |crowcliffe0@dion.ne.jp     |0|
|1          |Christoforo Rowcliffe  |crowcliffe0@dion.ne.jp     |1|
|2          |Justus Cockin          |jcockin1@virginia.edu      |1|
|3          |Kellia Shaw            |kshaw2@chron.com           |0|
|3          |Kellia Shaw            |kshaw2@chron.com           |1|
|4          |Dalt Fletcher          |dfletcher3@typepad.com     |1|
|4          |Dalt Fletcher          |dfletcher3@typepad.com     |0|
|5          |Sonnie Stryde          |sstryde4@theatlantic.com   |0|
|6          |Jane Dow               |janedoe@theatlantic.com    |5|
```

And I'm trying to filter/update the records such that if there are any employees with EmpVersion is 0 then I need to check if there are any other employees with the same Id,Name, Email and EmpVersion is 1 then delete the record with EmpVersion  0
if there are no employees found with same Id,Name and Email, then update the current employee record EmpVersion to 1

I want the output similar as

```
| EmployeeID | EmployeeName         |Email                      |     EmpVersion |
| --------   | --------------        | --------                 | -------------- |
|1          |Christoforo Rowcliffe  |crowcliffe0@dion.ne.jp     |1|
|2          |Justus Cockin          |jcockin1@virginia.edu      |1|
|3          |Kellia Shaw            |kshaw2@chron.com           |1|
|4          |Dalt Fletcher          |dfletcher3@typepad.com     |1|
|5          |Sonnie Stryde          |sstryde4@theatlantic.com   |1|
|6          |Jane Dow               |janedoe@theatlantic.com    |5|
```

Here is my Linq Query

```
 

       var employees = _dbContext.Employees.ToList();
        var EnployeesWithVersion0 = employees.Where(a => a.EmpVersion == 0).ToList();
        foreach (var emp in EnployeesWithVersion0)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Employees.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == emp.EmployeeID && 
                                        x.EmployeeName == emp.EmployeeName  &&
                                        x.Email == emp.Email && x.EmpVersion == 1).Any())
                {
                    _dbContext.Entry(emp).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var innerEmployee = Employees.Where(Employees.Where(x => 
                                           x.EmployeeID == emp.EmployeeID && 
                                           x.EmployeeName == emp.EmployeeName  &&
                                           x.Email == emp.Email && x.EmpVersion ==0).FirstOrDefault();
    
                        _dbContext.EmpVersion = 1;
                        _dbContext.Employees.Update(innerEmployee);
                        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    
    
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //Log Error
    
                    }
                }
    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              //Log Error
            }
         return employees;
       }
```

But I'm getting the error. An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ERROR [23505] [IBM][DB2/NT64] SQL0803N  One or more values in the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or foreign key update caused by a DELETE statement are not valid because the primary key, unique constraint or unique index identified by 1 constrains table dbo.Employees from having duplicate values for the index key."
Does anyone have inputs on this?

Comment: Is it possible to do it with just 2 (or even 1) sql statements without any application logic? Or is it necessarily to use this framework?

Comment: Are EmployeeID, EmployeeName and Email set with search values when FirstOrDefault returns Default ? Because if they are not and it appends at least twice then this code tries to create two entities with the same default values and EmpVersion = 1

Comment: @nfgl, I'm not sure what do you mean by "set with search value", Can you please explain?

Comment: I mean for example is innerEmployee.EmployeeName=emp.name when FirstOrDefault returns Default ? (I'm no c# prograammer), that could explain a SQL0803N.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if the where is no strict requirement to use some application logic.

```
CREATE TABLE T (EmployeeID, EmployeeName, Email, EmpVersion) AS
(
VALUES
  (1, 'Christoforo Rowcliffe', 'crowcliffe0@dion.ne.jp',    0)
, (1, 'Christoforo Rowcliffe', 'crowcliffe0@dion.ne.jp',    1)
, (2, 'Justus Cockin', 'jcockin1@virginia.edu',             1)
, (3, 'Kellia Shaw', 'kshaw2@chron.com',                    0)
, (3, 'Kellia Shaw', 'kshaw2@chron.com',                    1)
, (4, 'Dalt Fletcher', 'dfletcher3@typepad.com',            1)
, (4, 'Dalt Fletcher', 'dfletcher3@typepad.com',            0)
, (5, 'Sonnie Stryde', 'sstryde4@theatlantic.com',          0)
, (6, 'Jane Dow', 'janedoe@theatlantic.com',                5)
) WITH DATA
;

DELETE FROM
(
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER () OVER 
  (
    PARTITION BY EMPLOYEEID, EMPLOYEENAME, EMAIL 
    ORDER BY EMPVERSION DESC
  ) AS RN_
FROM T
)
WHERE RN_ > 1
;

UPDATE T SET EMPVERSION = 1 WHERE EMPVERSION = 0;

SELECT * FROM T;
```

| EMPLOYEEID | EMPLOYEENAME | EMAIL | EMPVERSION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Christoforo Rowcliffe | crowcliffe0@dion.ne.jp | 1 |
| 2 | Justus Cockin | jcockin1@virginia.edu | 1 |
| 3 | Kellia Shaw | kshaw2@chron.com | 1 |
| 4 | Dalt Fletcher | dfletcher3@typepad.com | 1 |
| 5 | Sonnie Stryde | sstryde4@theatlantic.com | 1 |
| 6 | Jane Dow | janedoe@theatlantic.com | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BM06-uNa)

Comment: Thanks but I'm using Entity Framework as ORM so not inclined to use SQL commands.